# Transparent file encryption is possible?

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, cryptography

Can we do cryptography, assuming that the name and extension do not change, by assuming the name and extension remain the same? The file does not appear to have changed. However, it shows the encrypted content at runtime.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++ and Windows?

Comment: I plan to work with C++ and Windows env.

Comment: If you think encryption relates to file extensions, I would strongly recommend you leave this to security professionals. Bad encryption is worse than no encryption; it provides a false sense of security.

Comment: I assume the extension thing is because he wants all files to open in their default applications like if they are not encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS already supports per-file encryption ([EFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-encryption)).

Windows Vista and later also supports full drive encryption with BitLocker. There is also a open source alternative called [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).

All of these solutions require a kernel driver and are probably one of the harder things to implement on Windows.

The only alternative I can think of is to fake a [cloud file service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/cloud-files-api-portal) by encrypting files when they are in the "cloud".